# by default value is not set in p:inputtext n jsf2

Tags: jsf-2, xhtml, el

i have two inputs with `percentageId_input_s1` and `percentageId` ids, in both 
inputs i want to set default values "0" when page gets load
value (0) is set in `percentageId_input_s1`. After loading `p:dialog` when i click on 
`p:rowExpansion` value is not set in `percentageId`, but when i use `p:inputText
id="percentageId" value="#{0}"` value is set in `percentageId` can any one tell me 
whats happening ??

**see code below:**

**abc.xhtml**

```
<h:form>
<p:inputText
id="percentageId_input_s1" value="0"
size="4" maxlength="4"
onkeypress="reset_column('#{p:component('columnId_select_s1')}');">
<f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" type="number" />
</p:inputText>
</h:form>

// other inputs with there own forms

<h:form>
<h:link>
// this h:link open/show below p:dialog 
</h:form>


<p:dialog>
<h:form>
<p:datatable>
<ajax event=toggle listener="#{someaction}">
// some columns
// using rowexpension p:rowExpansion
 <p:rowExpansion>
<p:inputText
id="percentageId" value="0"
size="4" maxlength="4"
onkeypress="reset_column('#{p:component('columnId_select_s1')}');">
<f:convertNumber integerOnly="true" type="number" />
</p:inputText>

// all closing
```

Comment: Please check whether primefaces watermark is what you are looking for.

Comment: You mean it doesn't work with `value=0`? The best way to have the `p:inputText` initialized is to bind it's `value` to a bean property and initialize it with `0` in the bean.

Comment: @XtremeBiker you are right but i do not want to use any `Bean` i just want to know why this does not work with `value=0` ? but this same does work with `value={0}` why ?